# Facing with some strange behaviour of State or Binding in didSet situation in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am updating my State variable with a Binding from another View, I have some code in didSet of my State, it would fired when I do set value from State, but not from Binding, for this reason I have to give a didSet to Binding of this State, which is not logical for me, Binding should Bind but it makes own version of that value with this advantage of updating State as well, I was wandering if it is a bug or it should be in this way! I mean I am expecting reference type behaviour in term of State-Binding, but with this down code, it shows more like Value type! Why this is happening? I was expecting didSet of State get fired even update coming from Binding!

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var someProperty: String = "Empty string!" {
        
        didSet(oldValue) {
            
            print("State didSet → " + someProperty)
            
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(someProperty)
            .padding()
        
        ButtonView(someProperty: $someProperty)
        
    }
}


struct ButtonView: View {
    
    @Binding var someProperty: String  {
        
        didSet(oldValue) {
            
            print("Binding didSet → " + someProperty)
            
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button("update Text") { someProperty = "Hello, world!" }
        
    }
}
```

---

update:

```
    struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var someProperty: String = "Empty string!" {

        didSet(oldValue) {

            print("State didSet → " + someProperty)

        }
    }

    var body: some View {

        Text(someProperty)
            .padding()

        Button("update Text") { someProperty = "Hello, world!" }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`didSet` works with `@State` only when you modify the `@State` directly but not when you change its internal value.

Note that the `State` is a *wrapper*. If you change its internal value (here `_someProperty`) using `Binding`, then `didSet` is not called.

You can use `onReceive` or `onChange` instead:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var someProperty: String = "Empty string!"

    var body: some View {
        Text(someProperty)
            .padding()
            // updated on changes only
            .onChange(of: someProperty) {
                print("State onChange → " + $0)
            }
            // updated every time
            .onReceive(Just(someProperty)) {
                print("State onReceive → " + $0)
            }

        ButtonView(someProperty: $someProperty)
    }
}
```

Comment: you said "didSet doesn't work with @State." but it work, have you tried? I mean it works if we update state from source of truth

Comment: First: I have issue with your code at .onRaceive, what is Just?

Comment: Seconde: Updated code for "didSet doesn't work with @State." It does! up

Comment: @swiftPunk Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use custom binding

```
var body: some View {
    
    Text(someProperty)
        .padding()
    
    ButtonView(someProperty: Binding(
        get: { self.someProperty },
        set: { self.someProperty = $0 }
    ))
    
}
```

Comment: your codes are working and acceptable as answer for me, but pawello was first, thanks!