# Swift : Why is my View Model with a binding not working with the Toggle in my View?

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding

I have a view with a separate view model for it's logic. In my view model I've created a binding and I want the Toggle in my View to reflect and act on this. But it the moment, the view reads the initial state of my binding, but it does not allow me to update it (I can't move the toggle box). And I have no idea why this is.

This is my View (simplified):

```swift
public var viewModel: MyViewModel // passed as a dependency to my view
var body: some View {
    Toggle("Test", isOn: viewModel.isOn)
}
```

This is the code in my ViewModel:

```swift
public var isOn: Binding<Bool> = .constant(false) {
    didSet {
        print("Binding in practice!")
    }
}
```

As I said, the code runs, and the initial value for `isOn` is respected: if I set it to `.constant(true)` or `.constant(false)` the checkbox is in the correct state. But I am not allowed to change the checkbox. Also the `print()`-statement is never executed. So it seems to me there are 2 problems:

- I cannot change the state for `isOn`
- The `didSet` is not executed

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit:**

So, actually some of you pointed my in the direction I've already tried and that did not work. In the above writing I simplified my use case, but it's actually a bit more abstract than that: I've got a protocol for my View Model that I use as a dependency. What I've got working now (with binding and observing) is the following:

ViewModelProtocol + ViewModel:

```swift
public protocol ViewModelProtocol: ObservableObject {
    var isOn: Binding<Bool> { get }
}

public class ViewModel: ViewModelProtocol {
    private var _isOn: Bool = false
    public var isOn: Binding<Bool> {
        Binding<Bool>(
            get: { self._isOn },
            set: {
                self._isOn = $0
                // custom code
            }
        )
    }

    // More code that has @Published properties
}
```

View:

```swift
struct MyView<Model>: View where Model: ViewModelProtocol {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: Model

    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Test", isOn: viewModel.isOn)
        
        // More code that uses @Published properties
    }
}
```

Once again, I simplified the example and stripped out all clutter, but with this setup I am able to do what I want. However, I'm still not sure if this is the correct way to do this.

The implementation of making my view generic is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/59504489/1471590

Comment: Does your answere? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759511/14733292

Comment: Why are you setting the binding to be a constant if you want to be able to change it?

Comment: @Abizern because I'm fairly new to Swift ;-) I've got the feeling I'm close, but just missing something basic here.

Comment: Thanks @RajaKishan! That answers my problem!

Comment: Using a constant Binding is exactly for that: providing a binding which cannot be changed. Thus your setter is a no-op. If you want it to be mutable, don't use a constant binding ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to drive your view from the properties of the view model, then make it an `ObservableObject`

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isOn = false {
        didSet {
            print("Binding in practice")
        }
    }
}
```

And in your view, you can bind the toggle to this value:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Test", isOn: $viewModel.isOn)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I simplified my example. The actual use case is that I pass viewModel as a dependency to my View and don't instantiate it in the view. Secondly, the dependency is actually a protocol, so I could use a property wrapper for it. I'll update my example to clarify it a bit more (and to test if my own found solution is actually the right one).

Answer (score -1):

After some more tinkering and the response of @RajaKishan I came up with the following solution that works:

```swift
private var _isOn: Bool = false
public var isOn: Binding<Bool> {
    Binding<Bool>(
        get: { self._isOn },
        set: {
            self._isOn = $0
            print("Room for custom logic")
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Your issue from first place was not Binding, you cannot use immutable value in your View!