# SwiftUI: Action not triggering with toggle

Tags: swift, swiftui, toggle, didset

I'm trying to trigger an action with a toggle switch. In this case the print message "value did change" doesn't show up on console after clicking on the toggle.

This is targeted for a macOS 10.15 app, .onChange will not work.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isToggle : Bool = false {
            didSet {
                print("value did change")
            }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: self.$isToggle){
                    Text("Toggle Label ")
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Facing with some strange behaviour of State or Binding in didSet situation in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65759392/facing-with-some-strange-behaviour-of-state-or-binding-in-didset-situation-in-sw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to shamelessly steal the first part of @Asperi's answer, but the second part is mine...

```
@State private var isToggle : Bool = false

var body: some View {
    Toggle(isOn: self.$isToggle.onUpdate({
        print("value did change")   // << here !!
    })){
        Text("Toggle Label ")
    }
}

extension Binding {
    
    /// Adds a modifier for this Binding that fires an action when a specific
    /// value changes.
    ///
    /// You can use `onUpdate` to trigger a side effect as the result of a
    /// `Binding` value changing.
    ///
    /// `onUpdate` is called on the main thread. Avoid performing long-running
    /// tasks on the main thread. If you need to perform a long-running task in
    /// response to `value` changing, you should dispatch to a background queue.
    ///
    /// The new value is NOT passed into the closure.
    ///
    ///     struct PlayerView: View {
    ///         var episode: Episode
    ///         @State private var playState: PlayState = .paused
    ///
    ///         var body: some View {
    ///             VStack {
    ///                 Text(episode.title)
    ///                 Text(episode.showTitle)
    ///                 PlayButton(playState: $playState.updated {
    ///                     model.playStateDidChange.update()
    ///                 })
    ///             }
    ///         }
    ///     }
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - action: A closure to run when the value changes.
    ///
    /// - Returns: A new binding value.

    func onUpdate(_ action: @escaping () -> Void) -> Binding<Value> {
        Binding(get: {
            wrappedValue
        }, set: { newValue in
            wrappedValue = newValue
            action()
        })
    }
}

extension Binding {

    /// Adds a modifier for this Binding that fires an action when a specific
    /// value changes.
    ///
    /// You can use `updated` to trigger a side effect as the result of a
    /// `Binding` value changing.
    ///
    /// `updated` is called on the main thread. Avoid performing long-running
    /// tasks on the main thread. If you need to perform a long-running task in
    /// response to `value` changing, you should dispatch to a background queue.
    ///
    /// The new value is passed into the closure.
    ///
    ///     struct PlayerView: View {
    ///         var episode: Episode
    ///         @State private var playState: PlayState = .paused
    ///
    ///         var body: some View {
    ///             VStack {
    ///                 Text(episode.title)
    ///                 Text(episode.showTitle)
    ///                 PlayButton(playState: $playState.updated { newState in
    ///                     model.playStateDidChange(newState)
    ///                 })
    ///             }
    ///         }
    ///     }
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - action: A closure to run when the value changes.
    ///
    /// - Returns: A new binding value.
    func updated(_ action: @escaping (_ value: Value) -> Void) -> Binding<Value> {
        Binding(get: {
            wrappedValue
        }, set: { newValue in
            wrappedValue = newValue
            action(newValue)
        })
    }
}
```

There are two Binding extensions to use from iOS 13, watchOS 6 and macOS 10. The first `.onUpdate()` fires when the binding value changes, but does not give you access to the old or new values. It is JUST for side effects. I used this one above simply because the `print()` did not need any other value.

If you need to use the newValue in your closure, use `.updated`. It works very similarly to `.onChange(of:)` except it modifies the Binding and does not give you access to the old value.

Answer (score 4):

In should not (at least never worked in such way), because `Toggle` changes not state itself (by direct assignment to property) but wrapped value via binding... use instead

```
@State private var isToggle : Bool = false

var body: some View {
    Toggle(isOn: self.$isToggle){
         Text("Toggle Label ")
     }
     .onChange(of: isToggle) { _ in
         print("value did change")   // << here !!
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i'm getting 2 errors. " Type '()' cannot conform to 'Equatable' " Highlighted on 'Toggle' and " Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type '()' "  highlighted on isToggle right after '.onChange'

Comment: Typo fixed (closure for onChange accepts new value). Tested with Xcode 13 / iOS 15

Comment: It works but since i'm working on a macOS 10.15 app,  it says that .onChange is only available for in macOS 11.0 or newer